# HTML Parsing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, cocoa-touch, parsing, html-parsing

I want to parse this site :

> http://its.wonju.go.kr/movinginfo2/DetailSub/StopDetail.asp?StopID=1959#

So I tried use TFHpple. Like this :

```
NSString *htmlWillInsert = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://its.wonju.go.kr/movinginfo2/DetailSub/StopDetail.asp?StopID=1959#"]
                                                    encoding:-2147481280
                                                       error:nil];

NSData *htmlData = [htmlWillInsert dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];

TFHpple *xpathParser =[[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *busNumbs = [xpathParser search:@"//td //a[@class='new']"];
NSLog (@"%@",busNumbs);

 for (int i=0;i<[busNumbs count];i++) {
    TFHppleElement *busNumb = [busNumbs objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *Numb = [busNumb content];
    NSString *st = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",Numb];
    NSLog(@"%@",st);
}
```

But it isn't working :(... 
It loads`<a href="#" onClick="MapMove(22);" class="new" onFocus='this.blur();'">▷ 22번(순환)`
But It can't loads `<font color='red'> 108분후 도착</font>` 
Like this :

```
2011-04-09 10:42:07.413 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 1번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.414 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 2번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.415 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 21번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.415 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 22번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.416 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 23번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.417 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 24번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.417 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 25번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.422 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 32번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.423 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 41번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.424 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 41-1번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.424 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 42번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.425 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 51번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.426 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 52번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.426 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 53번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.427 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 54번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.428 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 55번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.428 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 56번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.429 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 57번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.430 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 58번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.430 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 64번(기점 -> 종점)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.431 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 70번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.432 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 71번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.432 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 72번(기점 -> 종점)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.433 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 73번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.434 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 74번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.434 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 81-1번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.435 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 82번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.435 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 83번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.436 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 84번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.437 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 90번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.437 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 91번(순환)
```

What's wrong?

I want parse like this :

```
2011-04-09 10:42:07.413 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 1번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.414 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 2번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.415 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 21번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.415 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 22번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.416 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 23번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.417 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 24번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.417 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 25번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.422 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 32번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.423 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 41번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.424 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 41-1번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.424 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 42번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.425 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 51번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.426 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 52번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.426 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 53번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.427 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 54번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.428 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 55번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.428 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 56번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.429 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 57번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.430 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 58번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.430 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 64번(기점 -> 종점)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.431 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 70번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.432 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 71번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.432 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 72번(기점 -> 종점)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.433 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 73번(순환) 77분후 도착
2011-04-09 10:42:07.434 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 74번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.434 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 81-1번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.435 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 82번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.435 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 83번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.436 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 84번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.437 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 90번(순환)
2011-04-09 10:42:07.437 GangwonBus[5461:207] ▷ 91번(순환) 108분후 도착
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<font>` tag is a child node to the anchor tag. The description `[aTFHppleElement content]` is incorrectly [described](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) as the innerHTML as it  only contains the textual content of the element and not the content of its child nodes. So you will need to access the child nodes to display that information. As it were, the code in the repository doesn't provide the neccessary API to access the child nodes but one of its [forks](https://github.com/thepatrick/hpple) has the changes.

`[aTFHppleElement children]` provides access to the array of child nodes. It is an array of `TFHppleElement`'s. Looking at the HTML structure, only few of them have the child nodes so,

```
for (int i=0;i<[busNumbs count];i++) {
    TFHppleElement *busNumb = [busNumbs objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *out = [busNumb content];
    if ( [[busNumb children] count] != 0 ) {
        out = [out stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [[busNumb firstChild] content]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",out);
}
```

Comment: It has warning... 'TFHppleElement'may not respond to '-children' And 'TFHppleElement'may not respond to '-firstChild'.

Comment: Hmm.. are you using the [header](https://github.com/thepatrick/hpple/blob/master/TFHppleElement.h) from the fork? The warning you are seeing indicate that the methods aren't defined in the class interface and this should also result in an error if not implemented.